# Git: getting the ref of a commit by day?

Tags: git

How can I get the sha ref of a commit on a certain day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H" --since="2010-03-25" --before="2010-03-26"
```

Learn git via github: [git log tutorial](http://learn.github.com/p/log.html)